# How to CHANGE the location of a rectangle?

Tags: c#, rectangles

How do I change the location of where a rectangle is?

```
    private void Reset()
    {
        rndLocation();
        face1.Height = 30.0F;
        face1.Width = 25.0F;           
        lost = false;
        //change rectangle location
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Rectangle.Location property e.g.

```
face1.Location.X = new_X;
face1.Location.Y = new_Y;
```

Comment: Totally forgot about this.. Thank you! Is there a way to change the X and Y value at the same time?

Comment: face1.Location = new Point(x, y);